# Update SharePoint list item using phonegap

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

I could authenticate to sharepoint using azure ad and [azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) . I was able to get list from sharepoint but I could not update or create list item. This is my code to authenticate and get list. What I need is to create or update list item. I am reffering to This [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-cordova-multitarget)

```
var authority = "https://login.windows.net/common",
redirectUri = "http://my re direct url",
resourceUri = "https://my resource url",
clientId = "5a9hh56u-2485-7523-0122-j5k62463ab05",

var app = {
// Invoked when Cordova is fully loaded.
onDeviceReady: function() {
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', app.search);
},
// initialize authentication operations.
search: function () {
app.authenticate(function (authresult) {

    app.requestData(authresult);
});
},
// Shows user authentication dialog if required.
authenticate: function (authCompletedCallback) {

app.context = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
app.context.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (items) {
    if (items.length > 0) {
        authority = items[0].authority;
        app.context = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
        alert(app.context.webAbsoluteUrl);
    }
    // Attempt to authorize user silently
    app.context.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUri, clientId)
    .then(authCompletedCallback, function () {
        // We require user cridentials so triggers authentication dialog
        app.context.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, redirectUri)
        .then(authCompletedCallback, function (err) {
            app.error("Failed to authenticate: " + err);
        });
    });
});

 },
// Makes Api call to receive user list.
requestData: function (authResult) {
alert("Token : "+authResult.accessToken);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url =        "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WebServiceTest')/items";
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authResult.accessToken);

req.onload = function(e) {
    if (e.target.status >= 200 && e.target.status < 300) {
        alert("target"+e.target.request);
        var xml = $.parseXML(e.target.response),
        $xml = $( xml ),
        $test = $xml.find('Title');
        alert($test.text());
        $("#userlist").text($test.text());
        return;
    }
    app.error('Data request failed: ' + e.target.response);
};
req.onerror = function(e) {
    app.error('Data request failed: ' + e.error);
}

req.send();
},

error: function(err) {
var userlist = document.getElementById('userlist');
userlist.innerHTML = "";
var errorItem = document.createElement('li');
errorItem.classList.add('topcoat-list__item');
errorItem.classList.add('error-item');
errorItem.innerText = err;
userlist.appendChild(errorItem);
}    
};

 document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code above for updating or adding items what I can see.My guess is that you where using `GET` requests for those requests as well?

That will not work, you would have to use `POST` requests for that as outlined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx)